# Async/Await Multiple Linq Statements

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await

I have an API controller action that performs about 10 separate linq queries which are used to form a summary object that I need to send back to the client. These linq queries are all performed on the same data. Is there a way that I can use async/await in this scenario so that one linq statement doesn't have to block the others from running? If so, what is the most efficient way to write that async/await code?

To summarize my question:

1. Do I have a use case for async/await in this scenario?
2. If so, rather than create a bunch of independent tasks and then stuff them all into a Task.WhenAll(), is there a more efficient way to write this so that I can easily add more linq queries later on? (nothing too crazy, just clean and maintainable).

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetInventoryDetails(string id)
{
    var inventory = _storeInventoryRepo.FindByCondition(s => s.Id = id)

    var uniqueProductCount = inventory.Select(x => x.ProductId).Distinct().ToList().Count

    var totalProductInventoryValue = inventory.Sum(x =>x.UnitPrice & x.TotalUnits)

    var cheapestProduct = inventory.OrderBy(x => x.unitPrice).Select(x => x.ProductId).First();

    var inventorydetails = new InventoryDetails
    {
       UniqueProductCount = uniqueProductCount,
       TotalProductInventoryValue = totalProductInventoryValue,
       CheapestProduct = cheapestProduct
    }

    Return Ok(inventoryDetails)
}

    public class ProductInventory
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public double TotalUnits { get; set; }
    }
```

How would I use async/await to allow uniqueProductCost, totalProductInventoryValue, and cheapestProduct to execute without waiting for one to finish?

Comment: Could you add some code? Are these LINQ queries hitting a database or an in-memory data source?

Comment: @juunas just updated it -- does that help?

Comment: What's the type of `inventory`?

Comment: @juunas check my update

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my question. Is it an IQueryable<T> or IEnumerable<T> or something else?

Comment: Its an IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @juunas it is an IEnumerable<T>

Comment: In that case you cannot use async/await. You are doing synchronous operations in-memory. async/await is for scenarios where you do asynchronous work, e.g. calling databases or APIs.

Comment: If you want to run them in *parallel*, then that's a different question. Then you need multi-threading, not async/await.

Comment: @juunas so you suggest for this scenario to leave it as is? Meaning that it's already optimized?

Comment: Do you have to use Linq? I'm just wondering if the use of Dapper might help. You could run it as a single SQL statement to get the values you desire for `InventoryDetails`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working on `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IQueriable<T>`, you can't use `async-await`.

Unless you use `Task.Run`. But like using `async-await` with trully asynchronous APIs (like I/O) in ASP.NET you sacrifice performance for availability, using `Task.Run` will sacrifice availability for performance.

If you use `Select(x => x.ProductId).Distinct()`.[`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__), you'll allocate a lot less and use a lot less CPU than using `Select(x => x.ProductId).Distinct().ToList().Count`.

The same goes for using `inventory.OrderBy(x => x.unitPrice).First().ProductId` instead of `inventory.OrderBy(x => x.unitPrice).Select(x => x.ProductId).First()`.

Comment: how would you use count as described above it I need to get DISTINCT products?

Comment: My bad. I was thinking on [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/paulomorgado/linq-enhancing-distinct-with-the-predicateequalitycomparer) and ended up messing up the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have a use case for async/await in this scenario?

If you are sure you want to run these database requests concurrently.

Note that many database clients are limited to *one query per connection* - in EF terms, this means you'd need a separate db context for each query. This additional complexity (and overhead) may or may not be worth it; you'd have to determine that yourself.

> If so, rather than create a bunch of independent tasks and then stuff them all into a Task.WhenAll(), is there a more efficient way to write this so that I can easily add more linq queries later on? (nothing too crazy, just clean and maintainable).

`Task.WhenAll` is going to be the cleanest approach. You can pass a `List<Task>` to `Task.WhenAll` if that's cleaner for you.

Also, as noted in the comments, you'd want to use `IQueryable<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>`. It is the communication with the database that must be asynchronous, and that comes at the *end* of the LINQ expression.